# Top to furnace flue just blew off

Tags: hvac, roof

Sorry if this is posted in the wrong area.

Just a moment ago during a storm the top to my furnace flue blew off. Earliest someone can get out here to put it back on it Tomorrow.

How much damage will I be facing from the rain that will be going on all night? Furnace is located in the attic.

[image]

Comment: Does the flue go straight down into the furnace, or does it take a bend over to the side?

Comment: It goes straight down to the furnace .

Comment: Can you beg, buy or borrow a ladder to get up there yourself?  Are you comfortable doing so?  Alternatively, do you know any tradesman like landscapers or painters who would own a long fibreglass pole?  Is turning the furnace off until it's fixed an option?  If so rather than covering the opening you could simply ensure it drains by cutting or detaching it from the furnace.

Comment: Likely, little or no damage was done in a single rainstorm, unless it was a deluge. If you don't see damp spots under the furnace, and it works now, then the replacement cap is not urgent... until the next storm. Also, you or the repairman can drill a hole through the replaced cap and pipe and put in a small, self-taping sheet metal screw to prevent a repetition.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik make that an answer, I'll give it a vote.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, little or no damage was done in a single rainstorm, unless it was a deluge. If you don't see damp spots under the furnace, there's no puddle inside it, and it works now, then the replacement cap is not *urgent*... until the next storm.

Also, you or the repairman can drill a hole through the replaced cap and pipe and put in a small, self-taping sheet metal screw to prevent a repetition, similar to the way a [downspout is held to a rain gutter](http://www.insidespaces.org/howto/downspout/screw_downspout.jpg).